# Linking in AngularJS - $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have an issue with $routeProvider.

I have 2 views. First view is with a list of users. Second one, is the profile of a user.

In my first view, I have specified the link:

```
<a ng-href="#/view2/{{user.login}}">{{user.login}}</a>
```

In the js file of the view2, I have specified:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view2/:user', {
    templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
    controller: 'View2Ctrl'
  });
}])
```

And now, whenever I try to click on the link, it just changes the url to the following:

path-to-the-file:/index.html#/view2/blabla   where blabla is a user.login

So how can I make it work?

Thanks!!

Comment: you need to load page from `http` server not from `file://`. Easy to install a web server on your computer

Comment: oh. Any suggestions on how I can do that?

Comment: If you're on a windows PC just set it up in IIS. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc725762.aspx

Comment: lots of different web server packages you can install...pick one that best suits your needs

Comment: Thanks! I will try that once I get home, and I will let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

After using both ngRoute and ui-router, I would definitely use ui-router  for routing purposes (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

ui-router exposes a much broader API for daily tasks such as linking. For example, you can use a custom directive called ui-sref:

```
<a ui-sref="contacts.detail({ id: contact.id })">{{ contact.name }}</a>
```

Therefore you don't have to assemble links by yourself, the framework does it for you.

Comment: Is setting up ui-router the same as routeProvider?

Comment: I recently upgraded from ngRoute to ui-router and it was pretty quick. Read here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki